# Digital reading in arduino nano / atmega 328 is always 0 in a bipolar transistor

Tags: arduino, atmega328p

[image: Circuit tested with voltmeter]

{

```
// configura puerto 
    DDRD   = 0b0000000000;
    DDRC   = 0b0000000001;

while(1)
{
    printf("lee\n");
    // activa sensor X 
    PORTD = 0b0000000100;
    _delay_ms(ESPERA_SENSORES);
    lectura_sensor_x = PINC & 0b0000000001;
    printf("lectura %d \n", lectura_sensor_x);
    _delay_ms(PAUSA_EN_LECTURA);
    //PORTD = 0b0000000000;
    //_delay_ms(PAUSA_EN_LECTURA);
}
```

}

My target is to alternate the voltage level in IR emitter and Phototransistor, **0 to 5v**, and read the voltage value between ground and 10k resistor, *only when D2 pin is high*.

Everything works fine **without** the line connected to digital_read A0 pin (not ADC).

The values between ground and 10k resistor are 0.8 V or 3.26 V when I move an obstacle in the middle of IR emitter and Phototransistor.

When I connect digital_read wire the voltage fall down to almost 0, and the reading in arduino_nano is always 0 bit.

I've enabled and disabled the internal pull up resistor in A0 without success.

What's wrong?

---

My purpose about switching the voltage in optoelectronics components is to enlarge their usefull life.

As @Chris Stratton wrote, switching high/low the IR emitter is almost enough to reduce the current flow across the Phototransistor.

I omited the transistor, connected the phototransistor with a 10k resistor only and sense the voltage level in the transistor-resistor point.

I see that in IR emitter low state the current across the phototransistor decay to only 11%.  This is enough, I think so, to cool the component.

[image]

Comment: "only when D2 pin is high" Why????   Given that your enable is driven by software which could far more easily just decline to read the ADC, that seems rather overcomplicated.  It's also likely counterproductive - typically what you want to do in a situation like this is read the receiver with the LED on, and then with it off, and subtract.

Comment: Strip the code down to the bare minimum that shows the problem and post it in your question. There is a `{}` code tag button which will format it for you.

Comment: @Chris: S/he's using A0 as a digital input. See paragraph 2.

Comment: @Transistor - A digital input here is unlikely to work very well for this.  But that's beside the point, as any kind of input can be more easily *ignored* by software than disabled by external circuitry *under control of software*.

Comment: digitalread() returns either HI or LOW, how are you measuring the voltages across the 10k resistor?

Comment: Does the circuit work for you if you remove T1 and connect the resistor straight to the phototransistor? Also, are you sure A0 is configured as an _input_ pin?

Comment: I want to alternate the optoelectronics devices to keep them cold and enlarge their live.
The problem is not about code, also in the voltmeter lecture is almost 0 always.
I am reading it by C Code  {  lectura_sensor_x = PINC & 0b0000000001;
  printf("lectura %d \n", lectura_sensor_x);}
The circuit works fine without T1, without switching the voltage.  
A0 is defined as input by this {DDRC   = 0b0000000001;}

Comment: Switching off the IR LED is probably going to be more effective at controlling heating and life issues.  Unless you're operating the transistor at a higher than needed current.

Comment: Too many bits in those constants

Comment: Understand.  When switching the IR emmiter diode will close the current too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When D2 goes high it sets a voltage on the base of T1 and T1 is wired as an emitter follower and that means that pretty much what you put on the base gets reproduced on the emitter but about 0.7 volts lower and this is largely irrespective of what the emitter follower has as a variable signal in the collector.

When D2 goes low it turns off T1 and you'll see 0 volts across the 10 kohm resistor.

T1 seems to be superflous - if you just shorted it out (and removed D2 from driving its base) you should be able to read the collector signal of the optotransistor directly.

Comment: Sure. I've readed the optotransistor directly.  But I'll lost the switch on / off for the optotransistor I want.

Comment: Why do you need that functionality?

Comment: @Ando If you still want that weird functionality, then you could just place T1 below the resistor so T1 is connected to GND, or use a PNP instead and place it above the phototransistor. But chances are great that you do not need that functionality. Because it does not make any sense.

Comment: Switching is for improve an old design where optoelectronics components fails to soon.  I try to keep them working more time.

Answer (score 2):

You have configured `A0` as an output, and it's pulling the emitter of T1 low.

> A0 is defined as input by this {DDRC = 0b0000000001;}

`A0` is `PC0`, and you're writing a 1 to `DDRC0`. A 1 in `DDRx` means output.